# How to do a "since last activity" php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to figure out how to do a "since last activity" with mysql and php.

My app is very simple. Users can add different types of training and others can view their training.

I'm thinking to count the numbers of "new" records since the users last visit. But I don't have any ide how to do this.

Ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: take current login time  and last logout time and  use it like "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE createdate <= logouttime AND  createdate >=  logintime" ,  records should have an createdate.

Comment: I think I will go with this. Im having some problems thou i have two tables. `users` with `user_last_login` and table `user_traning` with `user_traning.date` with the input date. Cant figure out how to join the tables and count between those.

Answer (score -1):

You can

- count the number of items/records at the time of logout
- save it in database
- count the number of items/records at the time of login
- substract it from the logout count saved in database.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include some code? It's kind of a low quality answer.

Comment: Johan asked for idea, I gave an idea.

Comment: So let's say that for any reason, a lot of items are deleted from the database (some cleaning, done by the administrator for example). To keep it real, say 100 items are deleted. In the same time, only 5 items are added by users. Your solution will give a negative number of new items, which is clearly not what is wanted.